# How to solve this above discrepancy?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Using the rules for addition of fractions, we know that $1/3+2/3=1$. However, we also know that $1/3=0.333\dots$ up to infinity, and $2/3=0.666\dots$ up to infinity, and adding those two decimals we get $0.999\dots$ up to infinity. Now, according to the concept of limits, the above value approaches $1$, but is not exactly equal to $1$. Why does this discrepancy occur?

Comment: $0.99999999999 \dots$ is not approaching $1 $, it is $1$

Comment: The issue is thinking $0.\dot{9}$ and $1$ are not the same thing. This article discusses it quite well: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: How@Sine of the Time?

Comment: Note that $0.999\dots$ is a number, and it doesn't make sense to say that a number "approaches" another number. What we can say that is that the *sequence* $(0.9,0.99,0.999,0.9999,\dots)$ approaches $1$. Since $0.999\dots$ is, by definition, the limit of the aforementioned sequence, we see that $0.999\ldots = 1$.

Comment: Note that $1-0.999\ldots = 0.000\ldots = 0$ and also $0.999\ldots = 9\cdot\frac{1}{9} = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

One way is $\frac13+\frac23=\frac{1+2}3=1$, the other is $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3\cdot 10^{-k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 6\cdot 10^{-k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 9\cdot 10^{-k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 9\cdot 10^{-k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}9\cdot \frac{10^{-n-1}-10^{-1}}{10^{-1}-1}=\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}1-10^{-n}=1$$

I don't see a problem or a discrepancy.

Comment: How u got 10^(-(n+1))

Comment: @DEBSANKARROY With the formula $\sum_{k=1}^n x^k=\begin{cases}n&\text{if }x=1\\ \frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}&\text{if }x\ne 1\end{cases}$. You can prove it by induction on $n$ or read it in a book.

Comment: But how 0.9999... can be equal to 1?

Comment: Your method is absolutely correct@Dumper D Garb.

Comment: @DEBSANKARROY I know.